# How to remove picture from spreadsheet using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a few thousand spreadsheets with a logo floating on top.

I am using Microsoft Excel

I need to remove those images. I was wondering if it was possible with PowerShell.

I'm not allowed to install 3rd party apps

So far I have tried

```
$Excel = New-Object -comObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate($Excel)
$wshell.SendKeys('{F5}')
```

and so on

but that doesn't work

if I can send following keys while my excel is active

> 1. f5
> 2. Alt+s
> 3. Alt+b
> 4. Enter --selects all pictures
> 5. Delete --deletes them

then

```
$Excel.Save()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this

Hopefully, this will help others

Variables

```
$FilePath = 'E:\something\myfile.xlsx'
$FilePath = Get-Item -Path $FilePath

$Excel = NewObject -comObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true

$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
```

Open WorkBook

```
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath.fullname,[TYPE]::Missing,$true)
```

now the main part

```
$Worksheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item('data')
$Worksheet.Pictures().delete()

$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()
$excel.Quit()
```